rfishbase package
I have many Latin name in my database, I want to check them all in rfishbase package and find their common names and put them in to the new column.  I did not get success. I got an error.  if you have any idea, I would be appreciated. here is the codes
df_sample <- tibble(Latin_name = c("Sparus aurata", "Mullus barbatus", "Belone belone"))

#connect the fisbase database
fishbase_db <- fb_conn(server = c("fishbase", "sealifebase"), version = "latest")


df_sample <- df_sample %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Common_name = {
    result <- common_names(Latin_name, db = fishbase_db)
    if (nrow(result) > 0) result$CommonName[1] else NA
  })

print(df_sample)


here is the error message that I received.

Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: Common_name = { ... }.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in db_query_fields.DBIConnection():
! Can't query fields.
ℹ Using SQL: SELECT * FROM (FROM species) q03 WHERE (0 = 1)
Caused by error:
! rapi_prepare: Failed to prepare query SELECT *
FROM (FROM species) q03
WHERE (0 = 1)
Error: Catalog Error: Table with name species does not exist!
Did you mean "pg_views"?
LINE 2: FROM (FROM species) q03
^
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.


What's the error message, then?

I am sorry. I added it to the message right now

Thank you! Just tried in the meantime, am getting the same error with both the CRAN and the latest github version. Seems to be a recent open issue: https://github.com/ropensci/rfishbase/issues/276

The quote continues “… fb_tbl() function:
fb_tbl("ecosystem"). There are several outdated tutorials. Make sure you are using the most recent one for version 4. https://rdrr.io/github/ropensci/rfishbase/f/README.md

@I_O: I posted a response to the OpenSci issue page. I think this question exposed three errors: failure to load a local copy of the fishbase data, using a tibble as an argument to common_name, and failure to recognize that there are multiple values of `ComNam”.  I think the error message is from the first error, but that there would have been further errors had it been solved. I suggested that the issue be closed.

I suspect you have not followed the tutorial at: https://rdrr.io/github/ropensci/rfishbase/f/README.md
And also suspect that you are constructing a tibble to hold your data, whereas the common_names function despite it's first argument's name doesn't expect a tibble (or a list) but rather a character vector.
library(rfishbase) # after installation which took a loooooong time
fb_tbl("species", "sealifebase") # loads large table into memory

df_sample <- c("Sparus aurata", "Mullus barbatus", "Belone belone")
 
 CN <- common_names(
     species_list = df_sample,
     server = getOption("FISHBASE_API", "fishbase"),
     )
#-------------results
Joining with `by = join_by(Subfamily, GenCode, FamCode)`
Joining with `by = join_by(FamCode)`
Joining with `by = join_by(Order, Ordnum, Class, ClassNum)`
Joining with `by = join_by(Class, ClassNum)`
#------------------
 print(CN,n=21)
#--------------
# A tibble: 21 × 4
   SpecCode Species         ComName              Language
      <int> <chr>           <chr>                <chr>   
 1     1164 Sparus aurata   Bream                English 
 2     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilt head            English 
 3     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilt head bream      English 
 4     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilthead             English 
 5     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilthead bream       English 
 6     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilt-head bream      English 
 7     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilthead seabream    English 
 8     1164 Sparus aurata   Gilt-head seabream   English 
 9     1164 Sparus aurata   Silver seabream      English 
10     1164 Sparus aurata   Snapper              English 
11      790 Mullus barbatus Bluntsnouted mullet  English 
12      790 Mullus barbatus Blunt-snouted mullet English 
13      790 Mullus barbatus Mullet               English 
14      790 Mullus barbatus Red mullet           English 
15      790 Mullus barbatus Striped goatfish     English 
16      790 Mullus barbatus Striped mullet       English 
17       47 Belone belone   Garfish              English 
18       47 Belone belone   Gar-fish             English 
19       47 Belone belone   Garpike              English 
20       47 Belone belone   Greenbone            English 
21       47 Belone belone   Hornfish             English 
#-----------end results-------

Note that the common_names function will return a dataframe without needing to write a rowwise() loop or doing anything with mutate.
I didn't do this on a "clean" or completely up-to-date system:
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.1.2     rfishbase_4.1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] jsonlite_1.8.7    compiler_4.4.1    crayon_1.5.2      tidyselect_1.2.0  blob_1.2.4       
 [6] stringr_1.5.0     progress_1.2.2    yaml_2.3.7        fastmap_1.1.1     readr_2.1.4      
[11] R6_2.5.1          generics_0.1.3    curl_5.0.0        knitr_1.42        tibble_3.2.1     
[16] openssl_2.0.6     DBI_1.1.3         pillar_1.9.0      tzdb_0.3.0        rlang_1.1.0      
[21] utf8_1.2.3        cachem_1.0.7      stringi_1.7.12    xfun_0.42         fs_1.6.1         
[26] memoise_2.0.1     cli_3.6.1         withr_2.5.0       magrittr_2.0.3    digest_0.6.31    
[31] rstudioapi_0.14   dbplyr_2.3.2      askpass_1.1       hms_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.3  
[36] prettyunits_1.1.1 vctrs_0.6.1       evaluate_0.20     glue_1.6.2        duckdb_1.0.0-2   
[41] contentid_0.0.18  fansi_1.0.4       httr_1.4.5        rmarkdown_2.24    purrr_1.0.1      
[46] tools_4.4.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.5  

